# Clarification regarding solving ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let consider the differential equation $y'(t)=(y(t)^2-a^2)t-b$. Is there any method to solve this ODE? I was trying to solve by variations of parameters but it is not solvable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Ricatti equation. You can find out how to solve it in many places, here is one. https://www.math24.net/riccati-equation/